# Finite limit for a function that becomes infinite.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a function like this:

$$f(x) = \Big(1-\frac{1}{\cos x}\Big)\frac{1}{\sin x}$$

I need to evaluate the limit of this function when $x\rightarrow \pi /2$. A simple calculation shows that the function blows to infinity. Is there any way to get a finite limit out of this function?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean to ask is there any technique (or some mathematical manipulation) through which we can get a finite value of f(x) when x approaches pi/2.

Comment: The limit is unique. If it is infinite it remains infinite.

Comment: @Robert: Oh..okay.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\cos(x)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\cdot \frac{\cos(x)+1}{\cos(x)+1}$$

Comment: The limit is still infinite.